# Why does this cause an "invalid syntax" error with Google's Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, google-closure-compiler

If the following is passed into [Google code closure](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home):

```
return (function() {
    return true;
})();
```

it says there is a parsing error due to invalid syntax. What could be the problem?

Comment: Note that you are not *returning* an anonymous function but creating and *calling* an anonymous function.  So this statement is equivalent to just `return true;`.

Answer (score 4):

If that is your *entire* code, the problem is that you can't have a `return` statement (the first one) outside a function definition. Try:

```
function foo() {
    return (function() {
        return true;
    })();
}
```

Comment: Agreed. You can use the compiler's output wrapper if you are trying to  optimize an expression. Something like:
--output_wrapper="return %output%"

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be that you are using `return` as a top level construct (outside of any function body).  You need to wrap it inside a context in which `return` is valid:

```
var example = function () {
  return (function() {
    return true;
  })();
};
```